# Spatial join of multiple GDFs and extract values

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join, pandas, geodataframe

I have several different polygon geodataframes:
I would like to get the interseting area of one to another. I was able to do it like that:

```
frames = [oranzove, modre, cervene, tyrkysove]
empty = []
empty_pivot = []


for e, frame in enumerate(frames, 1):
    result = gpd.overlay(df1=obvody, df2=frame, how="intersection", keep_geom_type=True)
    result['area'] =result.apply(lambda row: row.geometry.area,axis=1)
    empty.append(result)

for i, empt in enumerate(empty, 1):
    #vytvořit pivot table
    result=pd.pivot_table(empt, index='MAPPA_ID', columns='NAZ_MOaMC', values='area')
    #vyplnit nulama
    result=result.fillna(0)
    #převézt na dataframe pro další práci
    result=pd.DataFrame(result.to_records())
    #převést na procenta
    result=result.set_index("MAPPA_ID")
    result=result.div(result.sum(axis=1), axis=0)*100
    result=result.reset_index()
    #překopírovat do prázdného listu
    empty_pivot.append(result)
    
oranzove_obvody=empty_pivot[0]
modre_obvody=empty_pivot[1]
cervene_obvody=empty_pivot[2]
tyrkysove_obvody=empty_pivot[3]
```

For example the output of oranzove_obvody looks something like that:

| MAPPA_ID | Name of district 1 | Name of district 2 | Name of district 4 | 5,6,7,to X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 50 | 30 | 20 |
| 2 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 90 |
| 3 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

But my goal was to create an short version of it which would only contain the number of district in the column names and the district name in the values.Like that:

| MAPPA_ID | district 1 | value 1 | district 2 | value 2 | district 3 | value 3 | district X | value X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name of district 2 | 50 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Name of district 2 | 10 | Name of district X | 90 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Name of district 1 | 100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I was able to do it like that:

```
oranzove_US=oranzove_US.to_dict()
oranzove_US 

oranzove_US_data= value of the dict
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(oranzove_data)

d = defaultdict(list)
for row, val in df[['MAPPA_ID', 'Krásné Pole', 'Moravská Ostrava a Přívoz', 'Plesná', 'Poruba', 'Pustkovec', 'Slezská Ostrava', 'Svinov', 'Třebovice']].iterrows():
    for col in range(len(df.columns)):
        if val[col] != 0:
            d[row+1].append((val.index[col], val[col]))
            
for i in range(max(len(x) for x in d.values())):
    df['obvod ' + str(i+1)] = [str(list(d.values())[j][i][0]) \
                               if i<len(d[j+1]) else None for j in range(len(d))]
    df['hodnota ' + str(i+1)] = [str(list(d.values())[j][i][1]) \
                               if i<len(d[j+1]) else None for j in range(len(d))]
    
#konvertovat objekty na čísla
df=df._convert(numeric=True)

#smazat první sloupec 'mappa_id'
df=pd.DataFrame(df.drop(['obvod 1', 'hodnota 1'], axis=1))

#přejmenovat sloupce
oranzove_obvody=df.rename(columns={'obvod 2':'obvod 1', 'hodnota 2': 'hodnota 1', 'obvod 3':'obvod 2', 'hodnota 3': 'hodnota 2','obvod 4':'obvod 3', 'hodnota 4': 'hodnota 3', 'obvod 5':'obvod 4', 'hodnota 5': 'hodnota 4'})

#maximální hodnota
oranzove_obvody['vetsinovy_obvod'] = oranzove_obvody[['Krásné Pole', 'Moravská Ostrava a Přívoz', 'Plesná', 'Poruba', 'Pustkovec', 'Slezská Ostrava', 'Svinov', 'Třebovice']].idxmax(axis=1)


oranzove_obvody.head(3)
```

This approach is possibly too complicated. But this was not my question. My question is, how to add new collumns (parcel 1 to X) from third polygon gdf called parcels, which are list of parcel IDs separated by ', ' to district 1 to district X inside oranzove gdf. So the output will possibly looks like that:

| MAPPA_ID | district 1 | value 1 | parcel 1 | district 2 | value 2 | parcel 2 | district 3 | value 3 | parcel 3 | district X | value X | parcel X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name of district 2 | 50 | 101, 55, 32 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Name of district 2 | 10 | 20, 10, 5, 11 | Name of district X | 90 | 6, 855, 22 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Name of district 1 | 100 | 225, 52 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The parcel 1 and parcel 2 in my example are parcels that are within the district 1 and 2 which is within the polygon oranzove. So in polygon 'oranzove' are in total these parcels (20, 10, 5, 11, 6, 855, 22), but only (20, 10, 5, 11) are also within "district 1" and only (6, 855, 22) are within "district 2".

Comment: Can you add a simple example of what you are starting with and your desired result

Comment: @BERA The last table is my desired output.

Comment: Can you share your data